# VS 2010 misses "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common Version=8.0.0.0" when running with SSRS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, report-viewer2010, report-viewer2012

Our project is built with VS 2010 and reports are built with SSRS 2005 and it works just fine, in this environment.
We are trying to migrate to SSRS 2012. In run time we get this error

```
'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I copied the file "MicrosoftReportViewerCommon.dll" to the bin folder, but its version is 10.0.x.x. I don't know how to find version 8.0.0.0.

I don't know exactly what we should do. Is it supposed to add this file to the project? Or the references in the project should be changed to refer to another file version?? And how this should be done??

In the web form we have this line of code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

and in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
   <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
validate="false" />
  </httpHandlers>
......
</system.web>



<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 2 days of searching the web, I figured out how to overcome this error.
I had to install [ReportViewer 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/details.aspx?id=4016), and this installer will register “Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common Version=8.0.0.0” in GAC automatically.

I've been told that is not a good practice and it is just a workaround, because the project is not running using the most updated controls and it is still using the old ones.

For now the project is working fine, but I hope some body provide me with a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a *similar* problem and found I needed **three** files:

> Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

And the config file looked like this:

```
   <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
   </assemblies>
   <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
   </buildProviders>
```